# Can we put "reflexive pronoun" between phrasal verbs that are not reversible?

Tags: word-order, phrasal-verbs

This question came to my mind when I used the phrasal verb "rely on"

E.g.

> Could I possibly *rely* **myself** *on* you?

I'm not interested in focusing whether the sentence sounds usual or not, but I need to clarify whether I could do this and the same on some certain phrasal verbs, to emphasize something that is done by the subject.

Quoted from OALD, I'm aware of the placement **somebody/something** is after the phrasal verb "rely on" i.e [rely on/upon + somebody/something]. Back to my question, if that's not possible, must I write like this instead? :

> Could I **myself** possibly *rely on* you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, you can't separate a phrasal verb with a reflexive pronoun used for emphasis**. Some phrasal verbs are not separable at all. Generally, those which are separable are separable because you can put the direct object (or very occasionally an adverb) between the parts of the verb. Placing a reflexive pronoun there would indicate that you are the object of the verb rather than emphasizing your role as the subject. In your specific example, it can't be done at all--*rely on* is not separable by a direct object.

Comment: Thank you, what about the second highlighted sentence?

Comment: @user516076 Yes, that's how you'd write it.

Answer (score 1):

The verb ***to rely*** is very rarely used reflexively. The sequence *[**he relied himself**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he%20relied%20himself%22) [on something providing support]* finds barely a dozen instances of those highlighted words in the entire Google Books corpus - and almost all of the matches seem to be either well over a century old, or from non-native Anglophones anyway.